# What type does function has?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I missed haskell's convenient operator $ so I have decided to introduce one.

```
class Applayable[-R,T] (val host : Function[R,T]) {
  def $: R=>T = host.apply
}
implicit def mkApplayable[R,T] (k : Function[R,T]) : Applayable[R,T] = new Applayable(k)
```

It has perfrectly worked for

```
val inc : Int => Int = _ + 1
inc $ 1
```

but failed for

```
def inc(x:Int) : Int = x+1
inc $ 1
```

What type should I specify for implicit cast to convert *def* definition to an Applayable instance?

Comment: `inc _ $ 1` works in your second example (with def)

Answer (score 7):

You cannot specify a type to do what you want: methods are not functions. You can transform a method into a (possibly partially applied) function by appending the magical underscore after it, like this:

```
def inc(x:Int) : Int = x+1
(inc _) $ 1
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to treat the inc method as a function by appending '_'. This works:

```
inc _ $ 1
```